# Point of continuiuty of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We have some wooden sticks each of length 10 m. Assume $0 < a,b,c < 10$ and we want to make 3 sticks of lengths $a,b,c$ by cutting the original sticks (we can not paste sticks together). Let $f(a,b,c)$ be the minimum number of the (original) sticks that are necessary to make sticks of length $a,b,c$. At what  points of the open cube $(0,10)^3$  the function $f$ is continuous !?

Comment: in practice you have to explicitly find $f$... I see no shortcut here

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Any ideal on how to write $f$ ?

Comment: You can easily define $f$ by cases. If $a+b+c<10$ then $f=1$. if $a+b<10$ and $c>10-a-b$ then $f=2$... and so on